# Run all tests without the @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) dance?

Tags: scala, junit, intellij-idea, specs2

Is there any way to set up IntelliJ's JUnit "Run All Tests" command to automatically pick up Scala Specs2? i.e. removing the boilerplate annotation in this snippet:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MySpec extends Specification
```

It's very irritating to have to remember to add this.

I've seen `SpecificationWithJUnit` but that is also a bit of a hack (and is incompatible with `TestKit`). I'm looking for a maven/sbt/intelliJ side solution.

Answer (score 1):

With Intellij, you shouldn't need the annotation to execute your specifications, because it has its own specs2 runner. I'm using IntelliJ 123.100 with a recent version of the Scala plugin (82 I think) and things work ok (except for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4798)).

Comment: That is true for individual tests, but not for "Run All Tests in..."

Comment: This also works for me. I can select the directory to execute (say 'data') and right-click "Run '!Specs2 in 'data'!'" (strange label but it works).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitPlatform])` instead `JUnitRunner`
Maybe this could help you:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.{DisplayName, Test}
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers}
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitPlatform])
class Junit5Test  extends JUnitSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def beforeAll: Unit = { println(">>> beforeAll <<< ") }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Example with JUnitSuite")
  @throws(classOf[RuntimeException])
  def throwsExceptionWhenCalled() {
    println("Запуск теста...")
    assertThrows[RuntimeException] { throw new RuntimeException }
  }

}
```

And `build.sbt` file:

```
val junitJupiter  = "5.2.0"
val junitPlatform = "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit"              % "junit"                   % "4.12" % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter"  % "junit-jupiter-api"       % junitJupiter % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter"  % "junit-jupiter-engine"    % junitJupiter % Test,
  "org.junit.jupiter"  % "junit-jupiter-params"    % junitJupiter % Test,
  "org.junit.platform" % "junit-platform-launcher" % junitPlatform % Test,
  "org.junit.platform" % "junit-platform-engine"   % junitPlatform % Test,
  "org.junit.platform" % "junit-platform-runner"   % junitPlatform % Test,
)
```